# Where should I start an activity which is suppose to be triggered when app goes to background?

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I want to start an activity but strange enough I couldn't find a single place that tells where exactly should I do that.

**Here is my code:**

```
    @Override   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled

    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTaskService.class); Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("foo", "bar"); service.putExtras(bundle);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service);   
  }
```

Comment: As per your code, you are trying to start a service from oncreate. Could you please explain your query in detail with your code snippet.

Comment: @Rizwan I am trying to implement Headless JS in React-Native which requires some changes in Adnroid native code as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Lifecycle component to detect if app is going to background.

Please refer the below code :

```
import android.app.Application
import android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner

    class SampleApp : Application() {

        private val lifecycleListener: SampleLifecycleListener by lazy {
            SampleLifecycleListener()
        }

        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            setupLifecycleListener()
        }

        private fun setupLifecycleListener() {
            ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle
                    .addObserver(lifecycleListener)
        }
    }
```

SampleApp is just an Android Application, declared in the manifest like:

```
<application
    android:name=".SampleApp"/>
```

Code for lifecycleListner :

```
class SampleLifecycleListener : LifecycleObserver {

    @Inject
    var component: MyLifecycleInterestedComponent

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onMoveToForeground() {
        component.appReturnedFromBackground = true
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onMoveToBackground() {
    }
}
```

In onMoveToBackground() method you can write your code.

For more information refer to [this link](https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-when-an-android-app-backgrounds-in-2018-4b5a94977d5c).

Comment: I am doing it in React-Native but needed to write some native code as well.

Comment: I don't have experience using native with react native